# Navigation Drawer Activity, calling fragments, null object reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

Where do I go wrong? I am trying to set editText in Communicate_fragment and pass it on to Recieve_Fragment and display it in a textView.

This would not be a problem If I did not use Navigation Drawer Activity, as I then can draw the fragments in the MainAcitivty, something I'm not able to do now, but I'm trying to learn how to implement it in this manner.

Please point me in the right direction as I am a beginner and trying to learn the crafts.

AndroidManager says:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void fragmentdrawer.recieve_fragment.setText(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

But I can't understand why.

Main:

```
package com.example.name.fragmentdrawer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import fragmentdrawer.about_me_fragment;
import fragmentdrawer.another_fragment;
import fragmentdrawer.communicate_fragment;
import fragmentdrawer.mainfragment;
import fragmentdrawer.recieve_fragment;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, communicate_fragment.TopSectionListener{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new mainfragment()).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

        android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.about_me) {
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new about_me_fragment()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.another_fragment) {
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new another_fragment()).commit();


        } else if (id == R.id.send) {
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new communicate_fragment()).commit();

        }
        else if (id == R.id.recieve) {
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new recieve_fragment()).commit();
        }

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    public void createMeme(String text) {

        recieve_fragment texten = (recieve_fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.recieve);
        texten.setText(text);




    }
}
```

Communicate_fragmentclass:

```
 package fragmentdrawer;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    import com.example.name.fragmentdrawer.R;


    public class communicate_fragment extends Fragment{

        private static EditText topTextInput;
        private static Button button;


        TopSectionListener activityCommander;

        public interface TopSectionListener{
            public void createMeme(String text);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            try {
                activityCommander = (TopSectionListener) activity;
            }catch (ClassCastException e) {
                throw  new ClassCastException(activity.toString());
            }
        }




        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_communicate, container, false);

            topTextInput = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.message);
            final Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);

            button.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener(){

                        public void onClick(View v){
                            buttonClicked(v);
                        }
                    }



            );



            return rootView;
        }

        public void buttonClicked(View view) {

            activityCommander.createMeme(topTextInput.getText().toString());



        }
    }
```

RECIEVE_CLASS_FRAMENT

```
package fragmentdrawer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.name.fragmentdrawer.R;

public class recieve_fragment extends Fragment{
    private static TextView textView;



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recieve, container, false);
        textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.displayMsg);
        return rootView;
    }

    public void setText(String text){
        textView.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Recieve_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/displayMsg"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />


</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the xml file for your receive_fragment class.

Comment: Probably the id for the textview is incorrect and therefore the findViewById() cannot find it resulting in a null.

Comment: @NarayanAcharya I have added it now, thank you!

Comment: Okay. Is it working now?

Comment: No, same problem @NarayanAcharya

Comment: The ids are wrong, `displayMsg` and `displaymMsg` in your layout and fragment respectively.

Comment: @NarayanAcharya Actually, that was just a typo in the text here, still the same problem

Comment: Does the fragment work when you use it without the communicate_fragment? As in without the callback.